# Can Wayland break Xorg?

Tags: x11, xorg, wayland

This is the sequence of events:

- Install Artix Linux (Arch derivative), using X11.
- Everythings works well for weeks.
- I make an update, including Wayland.
- I login with KDE/Wayland.
- Everything works, even if not perfectly.
- I login with KDE/X11.

  - The graphic applications that start automatically are fine.
  - The graphic applications that I launch do not start (I cannot even logout from the KDE main menu).
  - The text mode applications from the console (F2) work.
- System updates do not fix the problem.

Is it possible that Wayland modified some files shared with X11, that now are no longer recognised/interpreted correctly by X11?

Is it possible to have both Wayland and X11 installed, and switch from one to the other at login?

Comment: You almost never run only wayland, what you are probably running via the login choice is straight X11 when you pick X11, and Wayland + X11 wayland libs if you pick wayland. Console applications wouldn't change since they are running in the virtual terminal. What you want to do is determine if the applications not working are wayland or x11 programs, but it's such a general mess at this point that it's hard to really know. One thing that really holds wayland back is the huge mess of trying to debug the issues without having any actual debuggers in wayland stuff. Also check X11 log files.

Comment: on KDE, alt+f2 -> Enter "Kwin" and you should be able to open the KDE debug panel. It tell if you are running wayland or x11 per window